# ionic not recognized as name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, mobile

when I run the command it saying ionic : The term 'ionic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image]

Comment: Hi, where are you attempting to run the `ionic` command? Assuming that we are talking about the ionic framework for mobile development, which is a Javascript framework for getting websites to appear like mobile apps on mobile devices. It might be worthwhile reviewing the publisher documentation.

Comment: I use the visual code editor. suddenly it saying error after I install visual studio 2015 and MySql sever.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial... https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic2/

Answer (score 2):

npm install -g cordova

npm install -g ionic

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html